# List of nested lists to pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, list, nested-lists

I'm really stuck here.

I have a list of nested list to load into pandas. The list has 66 nested lists, each of these have 191 lists, and each of these have a dict with each actual values I need. See the image below, I hope it really helps.

I've tried every pandas method with no success (from record, from dict....), inside loops, etc., with zero success.

I need to end up with a data frame that has 11 columns (the deepest keys in the nested lists) and 191x66 rows corresponding to the initial 66 items.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems good old concatenation works.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in json_file], keys = files_names)
```

Found the answer in this question:

[List of lists of lists to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42868443/list-of-lists-of-lists-to-pandas-dataframe)